# Error When Creating Record from Related Entity

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I have a custom entity related to Account.
When I create a record of the custom entity from the Account an error message is shown:

**Error**
An error has occurred....
If this continues, contact your system administrator.

There is no problem creating the record from the entity itself.
There is a JavaScript function registered on-save of the custom entity that prevents the save if the record is a duplicate.
Why does the create/update not work from the related Account?

Comment: It should give you an option to download an error log - do that and paste it in your question. It will likely point to the exact problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problems is IE 10. I installed Windows 8 last night and do not yet have update rollup 12 installed.
The same error occurs when I try to add a contact to the Account.

Comment: You are saying you held IE 10 as a constant on both Orgs, the one with UR12 and without?

Comment: It was running fine yesterday with ie 9. I believe ie 10 is the problem because the same error is displayed if I add a related Contact or a related custom entity to the Account.

Comment: well, if you're confident, could I convince you to mark your solution as the answer ;-)

Comment: I must wait 2 days, any suggestion as to what to do until my hosting partner decides to install update 12?

Answer (score 2):

Although I agree with @PedroAzevedo's idea to turn tracing on, I disagree with his method because the CRM Diagnostic tool is a lot easier:  http://crmdiagtool2011.codeplex.com

I'd also check for a plugin registered on the update of the Account Entity.  It may be failing there, which would account for why it does work on the entity form itself...

Answer (score 1):

Active the [trace](http://exploringxrm.wordpress.com/2012/01/12/enabling-trace-in-microsoft-dynamics-crm-2011/) and see full error description. Another thing you can check is the security role, if you have permissions for the action AppendTo at Account.